# Python telegraph api. I can't understand how send image to telegraph via Python lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegraph

I'm trying to upload a photo from my hard drive to the telegraph. In the [documentation](https://python-telegraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegraph.html#telegraph.api.Telegraph.create_page) it says to use the upload_file():

*telegraph.upload.upload_file(f)
Upload file to Telegra.ph’s servers. Returns a list of links.
Allowed only .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif and .mp4 files.
Parameters:  f (file, str or list) – filename or file-like object.*

But I don't understand what "f (file, str or list) – filename or file-like object" means. That is, what do I need to do with the photo so that it can be passed to this function

my attempts to solve the problem:

```
upload_file(open('1.png', 'rb'))
```

error:
telegraph.exceptions.TelegraphException: File type invalid

```
myf = io.StringIO()
        myf.write(open(f'photo/{i}.png', 'rb'))
        print(upload_file(myf))
        myf.close()
```

error:
TypeError: string argument expected, got '_io.BufferedReader'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am loading images using this method

```
  
def upload_image_telegraph(path_image):
    with open(path_image, 'rb') as f:
        result_requests = requests.post(
            'http://telegra.ph/upload',
            files={'file': ('file', f, 'image/jpg')}  # image/gif, image/jpeg,image/jpg, image/png, video/mp4
        ).json()
        return result_requests
```

You can also download using the library Python html_telegraph_poster
With its help you can transfer both local images and a link to them
Exemple

```
  
from html_telegraph_poster import upload_image
res = upload_image('local path image or link image')
```